# allow user to set iphone receiver volume, not during phone call

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiosession

So far, my app plays audio through the iphone receiver (phone-call speaker) by using

```
AVAudioSession *ss = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[ss overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
```

I give the user an opportunity to set the volume using an `MPVolumeView`

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView1 = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 316, 300, 50)];
[volumeView1 sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView1];
```

However, adjusting the `MPVolumeView` is only affecting the volume of the phone's big speaker, not the receiver.

How can I present the user the opportunity to adjust the receiver volume when there is not a phone call in session?

Comment: I dont believe you have access to this, this is an iOS native function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, the following code allows the user to set the receiver's volume, although an audio file must be playing in the background. Also, the `AVAudioPlayer` *must* be a `@property`.

```
AVAudioSession *sharedSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[sharedSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[sharedSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];

MPVolumeView *volumeView1 = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 316, 300, 50)];
[volumeView1 sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:volumeView1];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"silence" ofType:@"m4a"]];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not allowed by the API, through public methods anyway. See apple's documentation on setting volume: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes I did take a look at that, but I don't see it mention that allowing the user to set the receiver's volume is not allowed in general. In other words, I'm wondering if there is some other method to accomplish it that perhaps doesn't involve MPVolumeView